# 1D-Texture Memory Limits

Tags: cuda, gpu, gnupg

I am a little bit confused about the limitations of texture memory. Is it 65536 or am i able to handle also arrays way larger.

At the Moment I'm using 2D-Textures. Bringing the problem to a 1D-Texture would make it easier.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of 1D textures in CUDA. Textures bound to arrays are read through `tex1d()` and are limited to a size of 65536 elements as you suspected in your question. Textures bound to linear memory are accessed through [`tex1dfetch()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-functions) and have a much larger limit of 2<sup>27</sup> = 134,217,728 elements. Check [table 14](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) of the Programming Manual.

Comment: This answer was exceedingly helpful when I tried to change my call like;
    
    cudaMallocArray( &cuArray, &channelDesc, 2048, 500 )// works
    cudaMallocArray( &cuArray, &channelDesc, 2048*500, 1 )// cudaError

Comment: Glad you found my answer helpful. While here, I've also updated the second link.